# Cannot pass variable from components to view

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a variable `tmp_sell` need to pass to QuoteAdd.vue, however no matter how many times and attempt still no luck, here is my component:

```
choosenProductSell(ev, p, i){
  var tmp_one_sell = parseFloat(d.data().p_sell);   
  this.tmp_sell = this.tmp_sell + tmp_one_sell;
  this.$root.$emit("tmp_sell", this.tmp_sell); //pass from component.
},
emitEventChanged () {

      this.$root.$emit('tmp_sell', this.tmp_sell);
},
```

and here my main view QuoteAdd.vue. I want o pass component variable to input, I've tries @tmp_sell="tmp_sell", tmp_sell="tmp_sell", but it still not showing up[image]

`{{tmp_sell}}`  keep showing 0 no matter how I changed tmp_sell in component.

```
<p>{{tmp_sell}}</p>
<input type="number" ref="q_subtotal" placeholder="Subtotal" @tmp_sell="tmp_sell" tmp_sell="tmp_sell" id="q_subtotal"   />

data() {
   tmp_sell: 0;
}
```

So Subtotal input tag is my field I want to show the answer. Any thing wrong with `this.$root.$emit("tmp_sell", this.tmp_sell);`? I struggle for a week already. Any help would appreciated.

Comment: so I do like `<input ref="q_subtotal" placeholder="Subtotal" @tmp_sell="getTmpSell"  id="q_subtotal"   />` it returns only 0

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your goal right.

Here is the very basic example of calculating the sum of product prices and sending the result to the parent component.

Pay attention to the names of events. It easy to make a typo in the name and Vue does not provide auto checks for this error.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const Products = {
  emits: ['update:total'],
  setup( props, { emit }) {
     const products = ref([])
     const total = ref(0)
     const generatePrices = () => {
       products.value = []
       for(var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
          products.value.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1)
       }   
       calcTotal();
     }
     const calcTotal = () => {
       total.value = 0;
       for(var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
          total.value += products.value[i];
       }       
       emit('update:total', total.value);
     }     
     return { products, total, generatePrices, calcTotal }
  },
  template: `Product prices: <ul><li v-for="p in products">{{p}}</li></ul><br/>
  <button @click="generatePrices()">Get Prices</button><br/>`
}

const App = {
  components: {
    Products
  },
  data() {
    return { total: 0 }
  }
}

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
li.active { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <products @update:total="total = $event"></products>
  Total: {{total}}  
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```